# comparing strings from a list in python but equal values do not appears as true

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, string-comparison

I have a issue while comparing strings from a list in python 2.7. I can see that the strings are identical by hovering the mouse above the variable in VS, but the program does not enter the last if of this piece of code:

```
result = [] # datetime object list
resultS = [] # dates converted in strings list
tipo = [] # verifying boolean list
oid = [] # object ids list
resultF = []
oidF = []
verifTCRA = False
# Keep the most recent dates and the type of data (if is TCRA or not)
with da.SearchCursor(fc, (campos), expressao) as sCursor2:
    for row in sCursor2:
        row0temp = row[num_campo1]
        row1temp = row[num_campo2]
        row2temp = row[num_campo3]
        if row0temp == None:
            row0temp = dataInicDt
        if row1temp == None:
            row1temp = dataInicDt
        if row2temp == None:
            row2temp = dataInicDt
        if ((row0temp > row1temp) and (row0temp > row2temp)):
            resultS.append(str(row[num_campo1]))
            result.append(row[num_campo1])
            tipo.append(False)
            oid.append(row[num_campo4])
        elif ((row1temp > row0temp) and (row1temp > row2temp)):
            resultS.append(str(row[num_campo2]))
            result.append(row[num_campo2])
            tipo.append(False)
            oid.append(row[num_campo4])
        elif ((row2temp > row0temp) and (row2temp > row1temp)):
            resultS.append(str(row[num_campo3]))
            result.append(row[num_campo3])
            tipo.append(True)
            oid.append(row[num_campo4])

MaxDat1 = max(result) # Biggest date of an AIA/NIS without TCRA
# If there is TCRA data, keeps in another list
for i in range(cont1):
    if tipo[i]:
        resultF.append(result[i])
        oidF.append(oid[i])
        verifTCRA = True
if verifTCRA:
    MaxData2 = max(resultF) # TCRA with biggest data in AIA/NIS
contInt = 0
MaxDat1S = str(MaxDat1)
# Keeps the object id of the data with the biggest date (tcra has priority)
if verifTCRA:
    for row in resultF:
        if row[0] == MaxData2:
            regCorr = oidF[contInt]
        contInt += 1
else:
    for row in resultS:
        #row0dt = dt.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        if (row[0] == MaxDat1S):
            regCorr = oid[contInt]
        contInt += 1
```

The date info is appended to the lists in both forms (datetime and string) because I was not capable of retrieving the date in the list to comparison and I must the datetime list to find maximum date

Comment: Print the repr() of the values that you are comparing. E.g. `print('Comparing %r vs %r' % (row[0], MaxDat1S))`. This will show any unprintable characters possibly filtered by VS.

Comment: It shows "Comparing '2' vs '2018-06-13 08:40:48'" ... kind of strange, 2 is not even the index of the list...

Comment: Good! Now backtrack and find out why row[0] did not get its expected value.

Comment: Ouch! ... I should had used 'if (row == MaxDat1S)' ... the code above is comparing just the first char of the string with another string. Sorry, my bad. Thanks for the help, bohrax, Paul.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

When using `list.append(x)` be careful, as lists are represented by reference in Python.
It might be appending the same exact list every time in the loop.
Try making a deepcopy of the list you wish to append first, which will create a *completely separate* object in memory to link into that list